# Condition evaluation and applying row numbers in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, teradata, row-number

I need guidance to resolve following issue.
I am trying to give row number based on condition.
Here is my condition:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY CLAIM_KEY, EXPOSURE_KEY, RESERVELINE_ID, TRANSACTIONSUBTYPE_DESC 
    ORDER BY TRANSACTION_CREATE_TS
)
```

Here is my table after applying above condition. (I just included one example here to simplify things.)

[image]

And here is what I want to achieve, but so far no results.

[image]

Comment: The current results are as expected, they are just out of order because you've ordered by the time period. Are you wanting to partition by transaction_create_ts as well?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The reason why I would like to reset the number from 0 when you see “reserve” second time in 7th line is , if previous “reserve’s” “reserveline outstanding reserve” is already 0, which you can see in line 3rd it’s 0 and it opens again with zero.  In this case I have restart from 1again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to consider using `RESET WHEN` as part of your `ROW_NUMBER()` window aggregate. `RESET WHEN` can include another window aggregate to allow you to look back at the previous row in the scope of the existing partition of `ROW_NUMBER` to check the condition of either the amount or close time stamp being NOT NULL.

The use of `RESET WHEN` is explained in Chapter 22 of SQL Functions, Operators, Expressions, and Predicates manual for Teradata 15.10. The chapter title is Ordered Analytical/Windows Aggregate Functions - The Window Feature.

Hope this helps set you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Rob Paller, RESET certainly helped! Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be working as expected.  Looking at your expected result set image, the rows where you manually added "1, 2, 3, 4" in blue text belong to the same partition as the first three rows:

```
CLAIM_KEY = 165,529
EXPOSURE_KEY = 158,038
RESERVELINE_ID = 101,692
TRANSACTIONSUBTYPE_DESC = 'Reserve'
```

That's why the ROW_NUMBER() continues to increment with 4,5,6,7.  Try adding  `ORDER BY CLAIM_KEY, EXPOSURE_KEY, RESERVELINE_ID, TRANSACTIONSUBTYPE_DESC` to the end of your full query, so you can see more clearly how the rows are being partitioned together and why the result set is the way it is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The reason why I would like to reset the number from 0 when you see “reserve” second time in 7th line is , if previous “reserve’s” “reserveline outstanding reserve” is already 0, which you can see in line 3rd it’s 0 and it opens again in line 7th, In this case I have restart from 1again.